# Permutation having some restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

How does one find the number of (a.) permutations and (b.) combinations of $n$ things, taken $r$ at a time, when out of these $n$ things, some $a_1$ are identical, $a_2$ others are identical,..., $a_k$ others are identical?

Comment: You meant others are non identical.

Comment: Not necessarily non identical. This restriction is similar to that of the permutation formula n!/a!b!c!.. , it's just that this formula applies to the number of permutations of n things taken all at a time. But what I'm asking for is a formula or method that would work to find the number of permutations of n things taken r at a time, given the restrictions above.